# Switching view controllers, but old screen stays behind

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have this method that usually works, but lately it has been giving me trouble.

What I am trying to do is to switch views without any animation to the switch.  For some reason, whenever I switch views, the old screen leaves some stuff behind, such as a button or a text field.

How do I get those to go away every time I switch views?

Here is what I have so far

.h

```
@class HighScoreViewController;

@interface StartUpScreen : UIViewController {
    HighScoreViewController *highScoreViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) HighScoreViewController *highScoreViewController;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "HighScoreViewController.h"

@implementation StartUpScreen

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    UIButton *highScoreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    highScoreButton.frame = CGRectMake(219, 0, 99, 55);
    [highScoreButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(goToHighScoresViewController)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:highScoreButton];
}

-(void)goToHighScoresViewController {
    HighScoreViewController *highScore = [[HighScoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HighScoreViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.highScoreViewController = highScore;

    //[self presentModalViewController:highScore animated:YES];

    [self.view insertSubview:highScore.view atIndex:0];
    [highScore release];
}
```

Comment: So, explain why you commented the -presentModalViewController method out, because it would work great if you passed NO instead of YES for animation.

Comment: well if i don't have that it does the same thing as if i do and just pass NO to it... so i see no harm in keeping it there... i will double check real fast and make sure that is not the problem though... thanks =)

Comment: yeah... i got rid of it and the problem is still there.

Comment: Got rid of what?  I said _keep_ the presentModalViewController and _scrap_ the insertSubview:atIndex:

Comment: oh, yup... that was the problem. thanks a ton!

Comment: Would you like me to post that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the

```
[self presentModalViewController:highScore animated:NO];
```

and comment out the:

```
[self.view insertSubview:highScore.view atIndex:0];
```

Lines and all will be fine and dandy.